# How to delete certain message in the future from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I would like to mark a certain message as a kind of `volatile`. I would like to get this type of emails removed automatically after a certain period of time - say one month.

My use case: I receive an order confirmation from an online shop. This email would be not needed in one month so I would like to have a mechanism that will delete it in the future.

Is this possible?

Comment: why not create a label/filter and send that label/filter directly to trash where it stays exactly 1 month and then it will be auto deleted